# Django How to override default form error messages

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

forms.py

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    emergency_number = forms.IntegerField(required=False,error_messages={'required': 'Enter a valid phone number'})
```

While validating the entered data is number,i am getting the default django error message `"Enter a whole number"`.Instead of that i want it to be `"Enter a valid phone number"`.

From Doc i used the above way,but same message is appearing.How to solve.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define your field like this:

```
emergency_number= forms.IntegerField(
                      required=False, 
                      error_messages={'invalid':'Enter a valid phone number'}
                  )
```

See in the docs that the error keys for the `IntegerField` are 4:

```
required, invalid, max_value, min_value
```

So you have to include the keys in the `error_messages` dict that you want to override.

By the way, `required` will never be thrown because you're specifying that `required=False`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I found that this is the simplest way to override the error_messages. I also didn't realize that there were default error keys for each form field, which made things a lot easier to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify message for `invalid` value also, as

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    emergency_number = forms.IntegerField(required=False,
         error_messages={'required': 'Enter a valid phone number',
                         'invalid': 'Enter a valid phone number'}
                        )
```